# strcpy()'s behaviour in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

As a task given by my teacher, we were told to write a simple class. Inside the constructor I wrote (C++ Visual Studio 2012):

```
void CCar::CCar(char* model){
    if(this->model!=NULL) delete[] this->model;
    this->model= new char[strlen(model)+1];
    strcpy(this->model, model);
}
```

I was told my code was wrong because I dynamically allocated memory with `new` , and I shouldn't have since `strcpy` allocates memory, so what I wrote exemplified a bad practice. Having included `<string.h>` without further `#define`s specifying secure functions as I was told to do, can you point me to a reference where `strcpy`'s behavior is specified thoroughly? Is my code *right*?

Comment: Whoever told you that, was lying. `strcpy` does not allocate memory. As to a reference - Google is your friend.

Comment: What kind of _teachers_ do you have?

Comment: My verification of NULL was redundant, it was out of costume. But my question was about `strcpy()`, and it has been answered by @IgorTandetnik. So yes, my suspicions were confirmed.

Comment: Your teacher is confusing `strcpy` with `strdup`.

Comment: Here is a specification of what `strcpy` does: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy . If it's not thorough enough for you, Google strcpy, and read the first 10 results.

Comment: @pts I know, I have read the article. But I was asking because "windows visual studio's flavour" of c++ is kind of non-standard, and maybe there was the relevant spec. Thank you for your interest, though.

Comment: In a constructor, you do not have any previously allocated memory to release, so you cannot know what `this->model` points at, but it isn't a valid pointer to allocated memory (because `this` is pointing to an uninitialized chunk of memory), so the delete is at best redundant and more probably harmful.  The NULL test would be superfluous even if the `delete[]` was not; `delete[]` on a null pointer is a no-op.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Now that I think it through, the delete would be harmful if this->model  wasn't NULL, understood. The bright side is, I learnt two things today :)

Comment: `if(this->model!=NULL)` causes undefined behaviour because `this->model` has not been initialized

Comment: `strcpy` is fully specified by ISO/IEC 9899:1999, you can download a copy [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcpy` does not allocate any memory.

In the C Standard the function is described the following way

> The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the
>   terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1. If
>   copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined. Returns 3 The strcpy function returns the value of s1.

where s1 and s2 are function parameters.

The constructor could look like

```
#include <cstring>

//...

CCar::CCar( const char* model )
{
    this->model = new char[std::strlen( model )+1];
    std::strcpy( this->model, model );
}
```

Or you could use standard class `std::string`. That is data member model has to be defined as having type `std::string`

In this case the constructor would look like

```
#include <string>

//...

CCar::CCar( const char* model ) : model( model )
{
}
```

By the way this statement in your constructor is wrong

```
if(this->model!=NULL) delete[] this->model;
```

It can result in undefined behaviour because for local objects of the class that have no the static storage duration data member model can have any arbitrary value. So there is an attempt to delete memory that was not allocated though model mignt not be equal to NULL.